# Changing the free wheel

Tags: cassette, freewheel

I'm thinking of changing from 8 speed to 9 speed. What are things I should keep in mind before changing free wheel?

Comment: You'd need to know if the derailleurs, chain, shifters, hub were compatible. If you post more information about your current bike - (model, age, components) someone may be able to give a more detailed response.

Comment: What's the underlying reason?  Generally this change is pretty expensive, unless you have most of the spare parts already from something else.

Comment: Do you actually have a freewheel or a cassette?

Answer (score 1):

Can the rear axle accommodate a nine speed cassette? Depending on your current equipment, you may have to change the derailer, hanger, and shifters as well.

Answer (score 1):

Rear hubs most of the time will accept anything from 7-9 speeds without modifying. In other words, any hub originally 7,8 or 9 speed should fit 7,8, or 9 speed. Regarding hub to cassette non-compatibility 10, 11 and now 12 speed cassettes are the ones that are not compatible. You will need a new shifter and 9 speed chain.

[image]

One thing to keep in mind after yo determine whether you have a cassette or freehub is to determine whether you have a uniglide, hyperglide or hyperglice C. That will dinnertime what compatible cassette you need.

[image]
Hyperglide 'C' (on left)     Non-Compact hub (on right)

There are maybe a half dozen other things to consider and keep in mind that I can't recall specifically but I can point you to a great source of info wich is where I would refresh my memory at the links below.
You may want to review my friend Sheldon's pages where he has a wealth of info on this and many subjects at:

http://www.sheldonbrown.com/k9.shtml

http://sheldonbrown.com/speeds.html

http://www.sheldonbrown.com/k7.html

Comment: There is also the new 11 speed hyperglide, which requires a spacer for an older cassette (8,9, or 10 speed).

Comment: I have heard of a spacer working for putting a 9 speed onto a 10 speed hub but not a 7,8 or 9 speed onto an 11 speed hub.